# Create configurable product in Magento 2 using REST API

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

How can create configurable product using REST API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How use REST APIs

### 1. Authentication

Magento allows developers to define web API resources and their permissions in a configuration file `webapi.xml`. Here are more details on exposing [services as Web APIs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html).

Before you can make web API calls, you must authenticate your identity and have necessary permissions (authorization) to access the API resource. Authentication allows Magento to identify the caller’s user type. Based on the user’s (administrator, integration, customer or guest) access rights, API calls’ resource accessibility is determined.

### 2. Construct a request

Each Magento web API call contains of a combination of these elements:

**2.1 HTTP verb**

- `GET`. Requests transfer of a current representation of the target
  resource. If you omit the verb, `GET` is the default.
- `PUT`. Requests
  that the state of the target resource be created or replaced with the
  state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message
  payload.
- `POST`. Requests that the origin server accept the
  representation enclosed in the request as data to be processed by the
  target resource.
- `DELETE`. Requests that the origin server delete the
  target resource.

**2.2 Endpoints for ConfigurableProduct**

```
GET    /V1/configurable-products/:sku/children
DELETE /V1/configurable-products/:sku/children/:childSku
PUT    /V1/configurable-products/variation
POST   /V1/configurable-products/:sku/child
GET    /V1/configurable-products/:sku/options/:id
GET    /V1/configurable-products/:sku/options/all
POST   /V1/configurable-products/:sku/options
PUT    /V1/configurable-products/:sku/options/:id
DELETE /V1/configurable-products/:sku/options/:id
```

**2.3 HTTP headers**

> To specify an HTTP header in a cURL command, use the `-H` or `--header` option.

Specify one or more of the following HTTP headers in your web API calls:

```
.---------------.-----------------------------------.
|  HTTP header  |                Syntax             |
|---------------|-----------------------------------|
| Authorization | Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>     |
| Accept        | Accept: application/<FORMAT>      |
| Content-Type  | Content-Type:application/<FORMAT> |
'---------------'-----------------------------------'
```

Where `<TOKEN>` is the authentication token returned by the Magento token service. See Authentication.

Where `<FORMAT>` is either [`JSON`](https://www.json.org/) or [`XML`](https://www.w3.org/XML/).

**2.4 Call payload**

The call payload is set of input parameters and attributes that you supply with the request. API operations have both *required* and *optional* inputs.

You specify input parameters in the URI.

You specify input attributes in a JSON- or XML-formatted request body.

**2.5 Construct a request**

1. Prepare `Authorization`, `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers to be passed to a request object. Use the Authorization token returned by the Magento token service.

   ```
   $token = 'token';
   $httpHeaders = new \Zend\Http\Headers();
   $httpHeaders->addHeaders([
      'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
      'Accept' => 'application/json',
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
   ]);
   ```
2. Open the [Magento/ConfigurableProduct/etc/webapi.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/etc/webapi.xml) configuration file and find the method needed (`generateVariation` or `addChild` in your case - I use `getChildren` method from [Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Api\LinkManagementInterface](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/Api/LinkManagementInterface.php) interface for example).
3. Set the headers, URI and method to a request object.

   ```
   $request = new \Zend\Http\Request();
   $request->setHeaders($httpHeaders);
   $request->setUri('http://yourdomain.com/rest/V1/configurable-products/:sku/children');
   $request->setMethod(\Zend\Http\Request::METHOD_GET);    
   $params = new \Zend\Stdlib\Parameters([
      'sku' => 'sku-needed-for-example'
   ]);
   $request->setQuery($params);
   ```
4. Prepare a HTTP Curl client object and pass the request object to `Client::send()` method.

   ```
   $client = new \Zend\Http\Client();
   $options = [
      'adapter'   => 'Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl',
      'curloptions' => [CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true],
      'maxredirects' => 0,
      'timeout' => 30
   ];
   $client->setOptions($options);  
   $response = $client->send($request);
   ```
5. This request returns a list of all childrens in `JSON` format. You can also specify `XML` format by changing `Accept` header of the request.

### 3. Use cURL to run the request

cURL is a command-line tool that lets you transmit and receive HTTP requests and responses from the command line or a shell script. It is available for Linux distributions, Mac OS X, and Windows.

To use cURL to run your REST web API call, use the cURL command syntax to construct the cURL command.

To create the endpoint in the call, append the REST URI that you constructed in Step 2.5 Construct a request to this URL:

`https://<MAGENTO_HOST_OR_IP>/<MAGENTO_BASE_INSTALL_DIR>/rest/`

For a complete list of cURL command options, see [curl.1 the man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

### 4. Review the response

Each web API call returns a HTTP status code and a response payload. When an error occcurs, the response body also returns an error message.

**HTTP status codes**

Each web API call returns an HTTP status code that reflects the result of a request:

```
.===========.=================.=================================================.
| HTTP code |     Meaning     |                     Description                 |
|===========|=================|=================================================|
|    200    |      Success    | M2 return HTTP 200 to the caller upon success.  |
|-----------|-----------------|-------------------------------------------------|
|           |                 | If service implementation throws either         |
|           |                 | `Magento_Service_Exception` or its derivative,  |
|           |                 | the framework returns a HTTP 400 with a error   |
|           |                 | response including the service-specific error   |
|    400    |   Bad Request   | code and message. This error code could         |
|           |                 | indicate a problem such as a missing required   |
|           |                 | parameter or the supplied data didn't pass      |
|           |                 | validation.                                     |
|-----------|-----------------|-------------------------------------------------|
|    401    |   Unauthorized  | The caller was not authorized to perform the    |
|           |                 | request. For example, the request included an   |
|           |                 | invalid token or a user with customer           |
|           |                 | permissions attempted to access an object that  |
|           |                 | requires administrator permissions.             |
|-----------|-----------------|-------------------------------------------------|
|    403    |    Forbidden    | Access is not allowed for reasons that are not  |
|           |                 | covered by error code 401.                      |
|-----------|-----------------|-------------------------------------------------|
|    404    |    Not found    | The specified REST endpoint does not exist. The |
|           |                 | caller can try again.                           |
|-----------|-----------------|-------------------------------------------------|
|    405    |   Not allowed   | A request was made of a resource using a method |
|           |                 | that is not supported by that resource. For     |
|           |                 | example, using GET on a form which requires data|
|           |                 | to be presented via POST, or using PUT on a     |
|           |                 | read-only resource.                             |
|-----------|-----------------|-------------------------------------------------|
|    406    | Not acceptable  | The requested resource is only capable of       |
|           |                 | generating content that is not acceptable       |
|           |                 | according to the Accept headers sent in the     |
|           |                 | request.                                        |
|-----------|-----------------|-------------------------------------------------|
|    500    | System Errors   | If service implementation throws any other      |
|           |                 | exception like network errors, database         |
|           |                 | communication, framework returns HTTP 500.      |
'==========='================='================================================='
```

**Response payload**

POST, PUT, and GET web API calls return a response payload. This payload is a JSON- or XML-formatted response body. The Accept: application/ header in the request determines the format of the response body, where FORMAT is either json or xml.

A successful DELETE call returns true. An unsuccessful DELETE call returns a payload similar to the other calls.

**Error format**

When an error occurs, the response body contains an error code, error message, and optional parameters.

```
.------------.---------------------------------------------------------------.
|     Part   |                          Description                          |
|------------|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|     code   | The status code representing the error.                       |
|------------|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|   message  | The message explaining the error.                             |
|------------|---------------------------------------------------------------|
| parameters | Optional. An array of attributes used to generate a different |
|            | and/or localized error message for the client.                |
'------------'---------------------------------------------------------------'
```